# Discount on all products in one category

Tags: discount

I want to have a 15% discount on all products in my "last chance" category. How do I do that? I tried making a rule, but nothing happens in the store.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Catalog Price rule under Promotions & try as below image **Under Conditions** , replace 283 by "**last chance**" category id....

[image]

Under **Actions**,

[image]

Under **Rule information**, make sure you selected required **"customer groups"**, **"Date settings"**

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Only problem, the sale price is marked as "wholesale price" in the store, not "sale price".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. Set condition (second tab) to has products from category last chance and then set actions (third tab) to apply 15% discount on related products.