# Sale on all products won't apply

Tags: magento-1.9, sales

[Discount on all products in one category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131550/discount-on-all-products-in-one-category)

I followed this tutorial and on conditions I selected all categories and applied it didnt apply sale on all products in the store

Then I removed categories with only the action tabs having the rule information and then saved and apply and it still isnt working. Any ideas? I am using 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating catalog price rule you must need to open that category product and click on save than an event will be fired and discount will be visible on the front.

Reference: [Catalog price Rule](http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/quick-tip-magento-catalog-price-rules-dont-work/)

Comment: I followed this in magento 1.9.2 version and it worked for me

Comment: Thanks! worked for me, hopefully it would get disabled again!

Answer (score 0):

Check followings

- You need to enable the Promotion rule
- You need to save and Apply rule
- Set the correct promotion start date ( Try past date, like week before as start update)
- Try indexing after

Comment: Did all of that, seems none of the rules i apply aren't applying. Is it a bug in magento or something else? It was working fine yesterday